# How to check if two values are in two columns or vice versa in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

So suppose I have a table `myTable` and this table has 3 columns `id`,`column1` and `column2`. Now I have two variables `$value1` and `$value2`. Now I wish to check if the is some row in `myTable` where **column1 equals $value1 AND column2 equals $value2** or **column1 equals $value2 AND column2 equals $value1**.

How should the SQL query statement for it be? Is it possible to write it in a single query? And if not, then what is the most efficient way to do it?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: You are on the right track - go for it. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood your query should be something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE (column1 = $value1 AND column2 = $value2) OR (column1 = $value2 AND column2 = $value1) )
```

Comment: Oh okay..Thanks a lot!